# Встраивание данных в бинарный файл (Vala/C)

Tags: linux, c, elf, vala, glib

Можно ли записать необходимую мне информацию (в данном случае - XML для Gtk-Builder) в бинарный файл? В Go для этого есть пакет `go-bindata`. А что с Vala/C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно Вам нужна `GResource - Resource framework` из библиотеки GIO. Библиотека GIO входит в Glib.